# Handle priority in two observable

Tags: rxjs

I have two stream with different priority.

Each event must play a sound that last for example 5s.
requirement are:

1. High priority event must kill lower priority sound
2. Otherwise every event must wait that previous sound complete

I have tried this way but also low kill high event
[example playground](https://rxjs-playground.github.io/#/?html=%3Cbutton%20id%3D%22myButton%22%3EHighPriority%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0A%3Cbutton%20id%3D%22myButton2%22%3ELowPriority%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0A&js=const%20button%20%3D%20document.getElementById%28%22myButton%22%29%3B%0Aconst%20button2%20%3D%20document.getElementById%28%22myButton2%22%29%3B%0A%0Avar%20high%24%20%3D%20Rx.Observable.fromEvent%28button%2C%20%22click%22%29.map%28%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20%27high%27%29%0A%2F%2F.subscribe%28x%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28%22click%22%29%29%0A%0Avar%20low%24%20%3D%20Rx.Observable.fromEvent%28button2%2C%20%22click%22%29.map%28%28%29%20%3D%3E%20%27low%27%29%0A%2F%2F.subscribe%28x%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28%22click2%22%29%29%0A%0Afunction%20playEvent%28event%29%7B%0A%20%0A%20%20return%20Rx.Observable.of%28%27ping%27%29%0A%20%20%20%20.do%28%28%29%20%3D%3E%20%20console.log%28%27start%20event%27%2Cevent%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20.delay%285000%29%0A%20%20%20%20.do%28%28%29%20%3D%3E%20%20console.log%28%27stop%20event%27%2Cevent%29%29%0A%7D%0A%0Ahigh%24.concatMap%28playEvent%29%0A.switchMap%28%20event%20%3D%3E%20low%24.concatMap%28playEvent%29%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%0A.subscribe%28%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tricky but I think it's doable by combining `concatMap` and `takeUntil`. I left a few logs to make more obvious how it all works.

```
const randomStream$ = defer(() => of(null).pipe(
  delay(Math.random() * 10000),
)).pipe(take(1), repeat());

let hIndex = 0;
let lIndex = 0;
const high$ = randomStream$.pipe(map(v => `H ${hIndex++}`));
const low$ = randomStream$.pipe(map(v => `L ${lIndex++}`));

merge(high$, low$).pipe(
  concatMap(v => {
    const sound$ = of(v).pipe(
      delay(5000),
    );

    if (v[0] === 'H') { // Item from the high priority stream
      return sound$;
    } else {
      return sound$.pipe(
        takeUntil(high$.pipe(
          tap(() => console.log(`${v} canceled`))
        )),
      );
    }
  }),
).subscribe(v => console.log(`${v} done`));
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jdbkhb

So all emission from `high$` and `low$` are turned into `sound$` that takes 5s. Then the logic splits for different types of stream:

- High priority stream is just returned and thanks to `concatMap` it really takes 5s for `sound$` to complete.
- Low priority stream is chained with `takeUntil` so when another `high$` is emitted it's completed immediately and the surrounding `concatMap` starts processing another one. If `low$` comes then it's queued by `concatMap`.

Btw, I don't know if you want to be queing emissions from both `low$` and `high$` because if you have multiple `low$`s buffered then they'll be processed in the same order as they arrived combined with emissions from `high$`.

So maybe you'll want to ignore all emissions from `low$` while there are pending emissions from `high$` but this will require I think one side-effect (variable outside of the chain) the will count the pending emissions from `high$` (or maybe just return `EMPTY` from `concatMap` when there are pending high priority items pending?).